# Wave Operators: Isometry

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

*This thread is only Q&A.*

Given Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}_0$ and $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider Hamiltonians:
$$H_\#:\mathcal{D}H_\#\to\mathcal{H}_\#:\quad H_\#=H_\#^*$$

Denote their evolutions:
$$U_\#(t):=e^{itH_\#}\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}_\#)$$

Regard an operator:
$$J\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}_0,\mathcal{H})$$

Assume the limit:
$$\Omega\varphi:=\lim_{t\to\infty}U(t)JU_0(t)\varphi\quad(\varphi\in\mathcal{H}_0)$$

Suppose one has:
$$\{J^*J-1\}U_0(t)\varphi\stackrel{t\to\pm\infty}{\to}0\quad(\varphi\in\mathcal{H})$$

> Then one obtains:
>   $$\|\Omega\varphi\|=\|\varphi\|\quad(\varphi\in\mathcal{H})$$

How can I check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By unitarity one has:
$$\|\Omega\varphi\|=\lim_{t\to\infty}\|JU_0(t)\varphi\|$$

It can be written as:
$$\|JU_0(t)\varphi\|^2=\langle\{J^*J-1\}U_0(t)\varphi,U_0(t)\varphi\rangle+\|\varphi\|^2$$

But it is bounded:
$$\|U_0(t)\varphi\|_{t\in\mathbb{R}}\equiv\|\varphi\|_{t\in\mathbb{R}}<\infty$$

So one obtains:
$$\langle\{J^*J-1\}U_0(t)\varphi,U_0(t)\varphi\rangle\stackrel{t\to\infty}{\to}0$$

Concluding the assertion.